# How to wait for observable to finish? Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have multiple calls that are being made and need to wait for all of them to finish before I can route to a different page. The problem I am running into is that typically I have been nesting web service calls, but for this case I have separate calls that may or may not be called based on input by the user. How do I wait for all calls that may or may not be called before routing to a new page.

```
submitButton_Clicked() {
  this.busy = this.service.call1() // must be called
    .first().subscribe(
      if (success){

        // **Logic to decide if call 2 is needed**
        ...

        this.busy = this.service.call2() // might be called
          .first().subscribe();

        // **Logic to decide if call 3 is needed**
        ...

        this.busy = this.service.call3() // might be called
          .first().subscribe();

        this.router('route'); // should route after all potential calls
      }
    );   
}
```

I am new to observables, so I'm not sure what the best way of doing this would be. Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you were using promises, you could use promise.all to achieve this. But I can see that is not the answer you are after.

Comment: Instead of conditionally subscribing to each, consider conditionally mapping each one to itself or to an empty observable and then merging or concatenating all of these possibly empty streams into a new stream and calling reduce and subscribe on that.

Comment: Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/28035/sending-multiple-sequential-http-requests#t=201702081844368442112 or http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/27973/sending-multiple-parallel-http-requests#t=2017020818445186661

Answer (score 1):

you could using flatMap

```
let Observable = Rx.Observable;

let f = Observable.of(20).delay(1000);
let g = f.map(x => x*x)
  .flatMap(x => Observable.of(x + 100));

g.subscribe(console.log);


/** 
 * Rx.Observable.prototype.flatMap 
 * and Rx.Observable.prototype.selectMany 
 * are equivalent.
 */

let h = f.map(x => x*3)
  .delay(1000)
  .flatMap(x => Observable.of(x + 100));
h.subscribe(console.log);
```

https://jsbin.com/vokofug/edit?js,console,output

or concat or merge:

> The concat() stream will print all of the values from source1 first,
>   and only begin printing values from source2 after source1 completes.
>
> The merge() stream will print values from source1 and source2 as it
>   receives them: It won’t wait for the first stream to complete before
>   emitting values from the second.

http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/PzKdVQ

```
'use strict';

const source1 =
  Rx.Observable.interval(100)
    .map(val => `Source 1: ${val}`)
    .take(5);

const source2 =
  Rx.Observable.interval(100)
    .map(val => `Source 2: ${val * 10}`)
    .take(5);

const concat_table = $('#concat-table-body'),
      merge_table  = $('#merge-table-body');

source1
  .concat(source2)
  .subscribe(value => {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = value;

    // Source 1 values populate BEFORE Source 2 
    concat_table.append(row);
  });

source1
  .merge(source2)
  .subscribe(value => {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = value;

    // Source 1 values INTERLEAVE with Source 2
    merge_table.append(row);
  });
```